# How to call set_index() on DataFrame?

Tags: python, syntax-error, pandas

My code requires the use of `set_index`.

I import:

```
    import sys
    import io  
    import csv   
    import math   
    from pandas import *   
    import numpy as np
```

I assumed that this would suffice. It doesn't, since I receive a :

NameError: name `set_index` is not defined.

I am using iPython EPDFree and pandas from PyPI (Riverbank computing). Is there a module I'm overlooking?

Comment: You need to show the actual code where you try to use `set_index`.

Answer (score 4):

`set_index()` is a **method** of DataFrames, not a standalone function. Are you calling it as a method e.g. `df.set_index(idx)`? Is it still giving you that NameError if you are doing it that way?

Comment: Thank very much @Harel , I was thinking of it as a function inside  a module.  

I have a list of dates, times. I'm trying to loop through all times for each date. The date is repeated for every time listed. (Always the same #). There are 62,035 rows. I say:

    data=read_csv(file)
    idf= data.set_index(['date', 'time'])

    for ((date, time), data) in idf:  


    # Or I also tried - for ind in idf:  
do something...

I get the IndexError: 'list index out of range'. Do you have any idea about why this might be occuring?

Comment: Assuming 'date' and 'time' are column labels of data, all you need is idf = data.set_index(['date', 'time']), see also:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html?highlight=set_index#add-an-index-using-dataframe-columns

Comment: The error is IndexError: 'list index out of range'. After using the following two lines of code:

    idf = data.set_index(['date', 'time']);
    for (((date, time), data) in idf):

Comment: Seems to me like the problem is in `for (((date, time), data) in idf):` and not in the call to set_index. Can you verify?